# View Controller presented modaly but the segue is a Show Segue

Tags: ios, swift

My app start with a `MainViewController` that has an `UINavigationController`. If a `show segue` to another controller, if the new controller has a `UINavigationController` it seems to be presented modally, but if I remove the `UINavigationController` it works fine.

Is this normal iOS behavior?

how can I navigate in the controller if there isn't a UINavigationController anymore?

Comment: is the root controller a navigation controller or MainViewController ?

Comment: The root controller is a SlideMenuController that in the mainViewController instantiate a UINavigationController (the login) and in the rightViewController and leftViewController another controller.

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing the view controller instead of presenting it?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you segue from your MainViewController (that has a navigationController) to a new ViewController, the new ViewController gets added to the MainViewController's NavigationController's stack.

If you segue to a new NavigationController from your MainViewController you create a new navigation stack and therefore iOS displays it like a modal.

To answer your question, you only need the 1 navigation controller on your MainViewController and all subsequent segues will be pushed onto the stack of that navigation controller. To get navigate back through the navigation stack to the MainViewController, have a look at navController.popViewController(animated: true).